# magento get Attribute code or object by label

Tags: php, magento

Help me 
How can i  get magento attribute code or object by label (if exist)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what you're asking. But you could get an attribute object by its label value like this:

```
$attr = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('frontend_label', 'Foo');
```